# imap_headers return string format

Tags: php, imap, email-headers

I'm trying to fetch all mail headers from an inbox using imap_headers($imap_resource) which returns an array of formatted string.

I want to know the proper/correct format of that returned string so I can parse/decode the string and break it down into date/subject/sender, etc.

Someone knows about this?

thanks

Comment: `print_r(imap_headers($imap_resource));` would let you see it, would it not?

Comment: that will display the array, and the array content is the formatted string, thus the question.

Comment: I guess your question doesn't make sense to me then. If you can see the formatted string, why can't you figure out how to parse it?

Comment: okay. let me make it clear to you. i want to know the format of the returned formatted string. Whether the date goes first, then followed by subject, etc.. got it?

Comment: But you can see the output the function is returning - thus you can already see the format of the returned string. I don't see a question here. Show us what `imap_headers($imap_resource);` is returning...

Comment: seen: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetch-overview.php ?

Comment: Or, if unsure on what the values mean see the RFC.  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-2.3.2

Comment: yeah. sorry for the, i guess wrong question. i was asking what kind of formatting is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `imap_mime_header_decode(string $text)` for this.

This will return an array of objects, where each objects has two properties: `charset` and `text`. You can start doing that and use php string functions to get what you wanted.